# How do I copy columns of two files as rows of a third file

Tags: bash, shell

File 1

```
dog
cat
spider
donkey
```

File 2

```
Bone
Mushroom
bug
grass
```

Output required

File 3

```
dog    Bone
cat    Mushroom
spider bug
donkey grass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right tool to merge lines of files is `paste`

```
paste file1 file2 > file3
```

Output:

```
dog     Bone
cat     Mushroom
spider  bug
donkey  grass
```

Answer (score 1):

Through awk,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' file1 file2 | column -t > file3
```

Example:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' file1 file2 | column -t
dog     Bone
cat     Mushroom
spider  bug
donkey  grass
```